# Printing from new Chromebook prints once and then queues other jobs

Tags: chromebook, hung

I have installed a new Acer Chromebook and connected to an HP6500 printer via a USB cable.  The computer recognizes the printer and does print one job after start up, but it queues all following jobs.  It requires a computer re-start inorder to print another job.

Answer (score 0):

The print driver is not hearing back from the printer that the job was completed.

Try a different USB cable.

Try a different USB port.

Try an updated HP Printer Driver for your Chromebook.

Finally, hook up the printer to a different (possibly Windows) machine and ensure the printer is working.